# I'd like to check the rate limit for requests per minute on the Steam Web API

Tags: javascript, steam-web-api

I'm fetching game information from the URL https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/ and then filtering the data using the logic with the URL [https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=${gameId}](https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=$%7BgameId%7D), and storing it into a database. However, I keep encountering a 429 error due to exceeding the API request limit, which prevents me from continuously injecting data into the database. I'm having difficulty finding precise information, such as the request limit per minute, on Steam Works and the Steam website. Just for your reference, I'm working on a web project that displays discounted Steam games.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            if (apps[i].name) {
                const { data } = await this.httpService.axiosRef.get(`${GET_GAME_DETAIL_BY_STEAM_URL}${apps[i].appid}`);
```

I ran a loop through the Steam API data, and if it iterates a certain number of times like this:\

```
                    if (i % 180 === 0 && i !== 0) {
                        console.log(`${i}s delay start`);
                        await this.sleep(1000 * 60 * 5);
                    }

                    console.log(newObj);
                }
```

I introduced a 5-minute delay using the sleep method. However, after a certain point, I encountered a 429 error, preventing further data injection.